# How to get the URI of DrawableImage Android

Tags: android

```
Drawable appIcon = packageManager
        .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
```

How to get the uri of `appIcon`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

use ContentResolver to open resource URIs

Answer (score 0):

The format is:

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

[package] is your package name

[res id] is value of the resource ID, e.g. R.drawable.sample_1

to stitch it together, use

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.sample_1);
```